# Tkinter not working with spyder - getting long error message in console

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

When I try and open a Tkinter window in spyder I get this error message in the console. Any ideas what's going on?

I am running spyder 3.1.4 and python 3.6.0.

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
2017 15:14:01.862 python[1119:46963] ‑[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc420e35d40
2017 15:14:01.872 python[1119:46963] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '‑[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc420e35d40'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff811fc57b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007fff964401da objc_exception_throw + 48
2 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8127cf14 ‑[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8116fc93 ___forwarding___ + 1059
4 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8116f7e8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5 Tk 0x000000011e1fac02 TkpInit + 471
6 Tk 0x000000011e1762a9 Tk_Init + 1794
7 _tkinter.cpythonm‑darwin.so 0x000000011d8deda4 Tcl_AppInit + 84
8 _tkinter.cpythonm‑darwin.so 0x000000011d8dea7b _tkinter_create + 1115
9 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e68da81 _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 497
10 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e70f787 call_function + 439
11 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e70bf62 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27346
12 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e7101ef _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2447
13 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e710d92 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 738
14 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e645677 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 247
15 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e645795 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 149
16 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e6454b0 PyObject_Call + 96
17 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e6a5aed slot_tp_init + 125
18 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e6a1e29 type_call + 313
19 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e645645 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 197
20 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e70f688 call_function + 184
21 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e70bf62 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27346
22 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e7101ef _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2447
23 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e7053d4 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
24 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e702b54 builtin_exec + 548
25 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e68da81 _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 497
26 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e70f787 call_function + 439
27 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e70bf62 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27346
28 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e7109ed fast_function + 381
29 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e70f761 call_function + 401
30 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e70bf62 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27346
31 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e7101ef _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2447
32 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e710a91 fast_function + 545
33 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e70f761 call_function + 401
34 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e70c001 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27505
35 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e7101ef _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2447
36 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e7053d4 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
37 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e702b54 builtin_exec + 548
38 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e68da81 _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 497
39 libpython3.6m.dylib 0x000000010e70f787 call_function + 439
```

There is more but it won't let me post it.